# Printing Perl Hash Keys

Tags: perl, hash, printing, key

I am trying to print out my Hash Keys in Perl, one per line. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Does this do it for you?

```
print "$_\n" for keys %hash;
```

Comment: `say for keys %hash;` in post 5.10

Comment: Is there a way to put that into a Perl/Tk program?

Comment: @perl.j: It's straightforward Perl; why wouldn't it work in a Perl/Tk program?

Comment: Well I am trying to put it in as the text in a messageBox but it isn't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: @perl It's not really possible to answer such a question without seeing the code.

Comment: Well I would hate to put all that code in a comment show the area of concern:   `sub show_index {
 my $index = $mw->messageBox(-type=>"ok",
                      -icon=>"info",
        -message=>
        -title=>"Index");
      }`                                                                        The blank message area is where I want the code.

Comment: Put this in: `join "\n", keys %hash`. It's a **very** different question from the one you asked.

Comment: @TLP: Thank You so much. You're great! +1 for you!

Answer (score 3):

Short version:

```
$, = "\n";
print keys %hash;
```

Or inside a larger script:

```
{
    local $, = "\n";
    print keys %hash;
}
```

To put it in a variable, for printing in a message box in accordance to your comments:

```
my $var = join "\n", keys %hash;
```

Comment: Is there a way to put that inside of a Perl/Tk program?

Comment: I don't think one should use `$,`. I mean, I like it too but I fear that most people would have to look it up.

Comment: Turns out, OP didn't want to print the keys at all, so the solution is the "join" thing, not the `$,` part. Besides, what's wrong with using such variables? They are there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

We can done this by using map function.

```
map {print "$_\n"} keys %hash;
```

map function process its statement for every keys in the hash.

Comment: The `map` function is there to transform a list. If you are using `map` in void context (i.e. if you're not using the return value) then you're using it wrong and should probably switch to using a `foreach` loop instead (for example `print "$_\n" foreach keys %hash` would work here). An alternative that uses `map` as intended might be `print map { "$_\n" } keys %hash`.